# RxJava 2 Observable with flatMapCompletable doesn't complete

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, completable-future

I have an observable that emits items and upload them to server.

Here is the code:

```
repository
            .getItems()
            .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "No items left."))
            .flatMapCompletable(item ->
                    repository
                            .uploadItems(item)
                            .onErrorComplete()
                            .andThen(
                                    deleteTemporaryItem()
                                            .onErrorComplete()
                            )
            );
```

getItems method emits items one by one and then completes, uploadItems method upload them to server. The issue is when there is no items all chain onComplete event just working fine and all my subscribers get this event and proceed it BUT when there were some items and all of them were uploaded onComplete events doesn't go further than  .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "No items left.")) method and all subscribers doesn't get this event. I added onErrorComplete to be sure that all methods after uploadItems completes and I also see in logs that all of them were completed but onComplete event from repository.getItems() doesn't go to all subscribers.

Could anyone please help to figure out what could be the reason for this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what the problem is. Could you please provide more information about your problem and method-signatures of used methods?

Comment: @HansWurst Hello! I just edited question! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I think there is some missunderstanding. DoOnComplete will be called, when, the observable has finished. The observable will only be finished if all values emmited from getItems() have been processed. If all items finished with Completeable.complete, the observable will complete. If one item, that is flatMapped blocks (larg file to uploaded) it will look like nothing is processing.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this example:

I pass the item through each step, so the subscribe will be notified on each item that has been processed. The processing pipeline involves uploading and deleting the file.

Please try to change the implementation and post a log of the output.

```
@Test
void name() throws Exception {
    Flowable<Integer> completed_work = Flowable.just(1, 2, 3)
            .map(integer -> integer * 1000)
            .flatMapSingle(integer ->
                    Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                        Thread.sleep(integer);
                        // do upload stuff here
                    })
                            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Uploaded file ...."))
                            //.timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .retry(3)
                            .andThen(
                                    Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                                        // do delete stuff...
                                    })
                                            .retry(2)
                                            //.timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Deleted file ..."))
                            )
                            .toSingle(() -> integer)
            )
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Completed work"));


    completed_work.test()
            .await()
            .assertResult(1000, 2000, 3000);
}
```